# Is there a way to concatenate variables in Neo4j-shell?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to concatenate "environment" variables in neo4j-shell. For example, after starting neo4j-shell (or using the -file option)

```
export LoadPath=file://path/to/dir
export Csv1=${LoadPath}/one.csv
export Csv2=${LoadPath}/two.csv
// start Cypher load csv statements
```

Then I would run a Cypher script that uses parameters Csv1 and Csv2 to load the appropriate CSV files. Is it possible to do this? So far, all my attempts to figure out the correct syntax has failed.

I'd like to be able to do this in a Windows environment so it looks like I have to build the variables within the neo4j-shell, rather than creating the variables before invoking neo4j-shell.

Comment: at least in Unix it's possible to write a shell script using input redirection/pipes for neo4j-shell. This allows for using env variables with neo4-shell: `echo "load csv from $myfile ... | bin/neo4j-shell`. Maybe something similar might be available on Windoze as well.